# How can I determine if local utility work is to blame for frequent power interruptions?

Tags: electrical

The power keeps going on and off like every two or three minutes and I don't know why. Are they repairing something or some cable wires near the palm coast area?

Comment: Call your power company, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: what should i tell them if i call them

Comment: Tell them about what you are going through, and they may tell you if there's a problem somewhere. If it keeps up you may want to unplug some of the things you do not want to have to replace.

Comment: Definitely unplug computers, cable boxes and other delicate electronics - they don't like being turned on and off rapidly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about a localized problem. Please rewrite it to cover the generic scenario that would apply to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your neighbors if they are experiencing this. Are the street lights near your home going dark too? If this is an issue with your home's electrical panel or within your home electrical system you may have a serious problem on your hands, like maybe even a fire hazard. Call the power company and/or an electrician right away.